# Vuejs trigger click to next child

Tags: vue.js, toggle, v-for

i have a simple v-for with few items and button. How can i trigger click event to next item inside v-for

**Template**

```
<div class="card" v-for="(card, card_index) in cards)">
    <div class="item" :class={'active': active === card_index + 'key'}
         @click="toggleActive(index)">{{ card.name }}
   </div>
</div>
<button>Next</button>
```

**JS**

```
toggleActive(index) {
    this.active === index + 'key'
    // some logic with card
}
```

How can i trigger toggleActive function, when i'm clicking "Next" button. Also i need to work it in a cycle ( when active is a last card and i'm clicking next -- active should be the first item) ?

Answer (score 0):

If I well understood your question you can use a numeric variable to identify the current active index and then change the `toggleActive` method in this way:

```js
  data() {
    return {
      activeIndex: -1;
    }
  },

  methods: {

    toggleActive(index) {

      if (index) {

        this.activeIndex = index;

      } else {

        this.activeIndex += 1;

        if ((this.activeIndex + 1) == this.cards.length) {
          this.activeIndex = 0;
        }

      }

    }

  }
```

```html
<div class="card" v-for="(card, card_index) in cards)">
  <div class="item" :class="{'active': activeIndex == card_index}" @click="toggleActive(card_index)">
  {{ card.name }}
  </div>
</div>
<button @click="toggleActive">Next</button>
```